# react-dropzone accepts all uploaded file types instead of specified file type(s) in "accept" parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone, react-dropzone

My `react-dropzone` `'accept': { .. }` parameter seems to be totally ignored when I am uploading files.

My `useDropzone({})`:

```
    const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({
        onDrop,
        noClick: true,
        'accept': {
            'video/mp4': ['.mp4', '.MP4'],
        },
    })
```

My `onDrop` Callback:

```
    const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {

        let test =  acceptedFiles.length || rejectedFiles.length
            ? `Accepted ${acceptedFiles.length}, rejected ${rejectedFiles.length} files`
            : "Try dropping some files.";

        console.log(test);

        if (acceptedFiles.length > 0) {
            setSelectedFiles(acceptedFiles);
        }

        acceptedFiles.forEach((file, index, array) => {

            const reader = new FileReader()

            reader.onabort = (event) => {
                console.log('file reading was aborted')
            }

            reader.onerror = (event) => {
                console.log('file reading has failed')
            }

            reader.onload = (event) => {

                // Do whatever you want with the file contents
                const binaryStr = reader.result
                console.log(binaryStr)

            }

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)

        })


    }, [])
```

The code:

```
        let test =  acceptedFiles.length || rejectedFiles.length
            ? `Accepted ${acceptedFiles.length}, rejected ${rejectedFiles.length} files`
            : "Try dropping some files.";
```

always returns:
`Accepted 1, rejected 0 files`

no matter what, `rejected` will always be `0` even when I uploaded `pdf`, `jpg`, `txt` etc

Here is the codesandbox Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-frost-zmyhd8?file=/pages/index.js

Anyone knows what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

According to [documentation](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-accepting-specific-file-types) you need to provide accept prop like below (without quotes) :

```
useDropzone({
  accept: {
    'video/mp4': ['.mp4', '.MP4'],
  }
})
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-kate-cumqok?file=/pages/index.js) is working solution.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I have changed to: ` accept: {
    'video/mp4': ['.mp4', '.MP4'],
  }` but sadly it makes no difference still, I still get `Accepted 1, rejected 0 files`

Comment: Can you create codesandbox?

Comment: Hi, I have added the codesandbox link

Comment: I updated my answer with working example

Answer (score 2):

You would have to give different mime types for different file formats:
After reviewing different this way I was able to resolve the issues that I faced related to MIME types.

For doc, text, or pdf files:

```
useDropzone({
      accept: {
        "application/pdf": [".pdf"],
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document":
          [".docx"],
        "application/msword": [".doc"],
        "text/plain": [".txt"],
      },
    });
```

For audio/video files:

```
 useDropzone({
      onDrop,
      maxFiles: 1,
      accept: {
        "audio/mpeg": [".mp3"],
        "audio/wav": [".wav"],
        "audio/webm": [".webm"],
        "audio/flac": [".flac"],
        "audio/x-m4a": [".m4a"],

        "video/mp4": [".mp4"],
        "video/mpeg": [".mpeg"],
        "video/webm": [".webm"],
      },
    });
```

You guys can also refer to official common MIME types -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#src) now says:

> Note that the onDrop callback will always be invoked regardless if the dropped files were accepted or rejected. If you'd like to react to a specific scenario, use the onDropAccepted/onDropRejected props.

However the function signature is misleading because the parameter is named `acceptedFiles` even though it's a mix of both accepted and rejected files:

```js
function onDrop(acceptedFiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **fileRejections** instead of **rejectedFiles** to achieve this

```
const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive, fileRejections, acceptedFiles} = useDropzone({
        onDrop,
        noClick: true,
        'accept': {
            'video/mp4': ['.mp4', '.MP4'],
        },
    })
```